# Transaction Log File corruption on Mirror server SQL 2017

Tags: transaction-log, mirroring

Wondering if anyone has encountered database transaction log file corruption when database mirroring is enabled in SQL 2017 running on Windows Server 2019, on the Mirror server?

If so, curious what steps where taken to correct it.

Some background on what we are experiencing:

We recently upgraded both our Principal and Mirror servers from Windows Server 2016/SQL 2016 to Windows Server 2019/SQL Server 2017 (14.0.3162.1). We have 23 databases configured for mirroring and since our upgrade, 1 or 2 databases will have mirroring suspended every 24 hours or so.

These events are generated on the Principal and Mirror servers when mirroring is suspended:

Database mirroring will be suspended. Server instance ‘MyServer’ encountered error 9004, state 3, severity 21 when it was acting as a mirroring partner for database ‘MyDatabase’. The database mirroring partners might try to recover automatically from the error and resume the mirroring session. For more information, view the error log for additional error messages.

And this additional error is generated on the Mirror Server:

An error occurred while processing the log for database 'MyDatabase'.  If possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log.

When we try to resume the suspended mirroring session, it will throw this error again on the Mirror server:

An error occurred while processing the log for database 'MyDatabase'.  If possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log.

Our only course of action to bring mirroring back online, is to rebuild it. E.g. We take a Full and Transaction log backup on the Principal, then restore it to Mirror. Then we can enable mirroring, and everything is fine again.

Some interesting things we have observed:

1.) We have encountered this issue in both High Safety and High-Performance mirroring modes.

2.) We have also encountered this issue, when we are failed over (Principal and Mirror roles are flipped between servers). The normal “principal” server (which is now acting as the mirror) will eventually have transaction log file corruption.

3.) Windows Server 2019 Defender seems to play a role in how often we are seeing mirroring sessions suspended. When Defender is enabled, we experience 2-3 corruptions/mirroring sessions suspended per 24-hour period. When Defender is disabled, we only experience 1 or 2 corruptions/mirroring sessions suspended per 24-hour period.

4.) In our troubleshooting, when we run dbcc checkdb() on the Mirror server’s Database that was suspended, dbcc checkdb() does report corruption errors (b-tree errors). However, when we run dbcc checkdb() on the Principal Server’s Database – dbcc checkdb() reports 0 errors.

5.) We have rebuilt the database transaction log file (on the Principal server) for the database that experienced corruption on the Mirror, before enabling mirroring again. Issue came back roughly 24 hours later.

6.) Windows App, System Events are not reporting any system issues.

7.) SQL Server logs are not reporting any SQL events (other than these mirroring errors)

8.) There doesn’t seem to be a pattern/time of day to when corruption will strike on the Mirror

9.) We log our Principal Server SQL activity and we aren’t seeing anything out of the ordinary when corruption strikes on the Mirror. (Wait stats, query activity - all seem normal)

Any thoughts or troubleshooting advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since you have tested all possible test cases - I think it is a bug and you should report it to MS.

Comment: We do have a support ticket open with them, but so far the support reps have been giving us this generic response:

Greetings!

From the error number 9004 it seems some log file corruption is happening. I would suggest the following to handle this issue:

1. Change the log file location for the Principal and the Mirror databases.
2. During this change rebuild the log file of both the databases.
3. Ensure that the log file drive is not shared by any other data files.

Please let me know if you have any questions or concerns.

Not very helpful...